# Redirecionar url para url:porta htaccess

Tags: node.js, htaccess

Esteu utilizando node para rodar minha aplicação e nao consigo configurar o htaccess para apontar para porta que eu defini

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^dashponto.softmarketing.com.br$ [OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^dashponto.softmarketing.com.br$
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://dashponto.softmarketing.com.br:1589/$1 [P]
```

Comment: Estás a correr o Node com Apache? O melhor acho que seria fazer isso no NodeJS.

Comment: sim apache2....

Comment: Use ProxyReverse no seu virtualHost, assim vc configura endereço a porta que o sistema vai utilizar.

Comment: npm proxyreverse?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Problema com o socket.io, tem q definir com a porta

```
var socket = io('http://dashponto.softmarketing.com.br:1589');
```

Comment: quer dizer que resolveu? Então a idéia em mexer no rewriterule não faz sentido.

Comment: rewrite é pra eliminar a porta...

Comment: aham.. entendi tudo